# Laravel view count increments even with session

Tags: laravel, session, increment

My view count still increments even though I have session can any one tell what is wrong with my code?

```
if(! ( Session::get($id) == $id)){
        Post::where('id', $id)->increment('view_count');
        dd('added count');
        Session::put('id', $id);
      }
```

The id is the blog->id

Comment: You can now use `Session::increment($id)` in 5.2.40+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
if(! ( Session::get('id') == $id)){
    Post::where('id', $id)->increment('view_count');
    dd('added count');
    Session::put('id', $id);
  }
```

change `Session::get($id)` to `Session::get('id')`